# Why we use Service layer and DAO with JPA repository

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa, repository-pattern, dao

Why we use Service layer and DAO with JPA repository.
Is there any standard for using this architecture in spring mvc projects?
I am confuse about this and I am new in spring mvc. 
Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: We use service layer generally to abstract out the DAO layer. The business layer should not be aware of which ORM we are using. It should talk only to the service layer. It also helps if you were to switch your DAO layer.

Comment: When we are talking using JPA Repository (I believe you are talking about Spring Data JPA), it is usually related to domain driven design, and in DDD people usually consider Repository to be in Domain layer, and there is no so called DAO layer in such design.  Repository is usually considered to be more abstracted concept while DAO serves for more technical purpose (ahh... it is hard to explain in such a short paragraph)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using spring MVC and in my project I have 3 layers

1. Controller
2. Service
3. DAO

Controller simply controls in/out of the project.In controller we do not write any business logics

We write all the business logic in service layer

In dao, we write the database logic like CRUD Operations

This is done as we do not wish to  mix all the logic flows in a single class. It will increase burden and hard to debug

Answer (score 1):

There are two reason to use Service layer:

**1. Code Modularity:**

Using Service layer we can separate the code into different layers like for ORM and Business logic.

**2. Security**

Service layer that has no relation to the DB, then is it more difficult to gain access to the DB from the client except through the service. If the DB cannot be accessed directly from the client (and there is no trivial DAO module acting as the service) then all an attacker who has taken over the client can do is attempt to hack the service layer as well before he gets all but the most sanitised access to your data.